# How can I check google extension storage before an SubjectBehavior?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension, rxjs

I've an authentication guard that checks results from a `BehaviorSubject` but, before checking it, I need to check chrome local storage that return values in a callback and if the token is invalid renew it and inform `BehaviorSubject` to allow specific route.

How can I check local storage in `get` function?

Follow the code to better understand the flow.

**auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn
      .take(1)
      .map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      });
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
    private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    get isLoggedIn() {
        // Here I need check Google Storage that return a callback
        // The sintax for is chrome.storage.sync.get('keys', callback);
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason that turning chrome storage into an observable based API doesn't work for you?

Comment: Turning chrome storage into a observable is a unneeded complex solution, that don't consider subsequent request to get a new token. But thanks for your help and answer, maybe this help others that need a similar solution.

Comment: uh, using the create operator really isn't remotely complex haha... and it does consider the subsequent request because now you have an observable.  Observables and Callbacks are just 2 methods of dealing with asynchronous operations, Right now you're struggling because you're trying to mix one method with another, it's trivial if both are observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all you are doing then you don't need to use observables. You aren't doing anything asynchronous. You just want to check the current value of local storage to see if the user is still authenticated.

The CanActivate interface allows you to return `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`. So you could just do something like this:

**auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
       return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
    get isLoggedIn() {
        return localStorage.getItem('my-auth-key');
    }
}
```

If you need to expose the authentication state as an observable for other reasons in your app then you could set a timer when you put their session in local storage. It could either poll on an acceptable interval, set it to the absolute expiration of the session, or something like that depending on your authentication scheme. The basic concept is that the only way to make your localstorage "observable" is to use a timer or some event.

For one app I worked on we have a token with an absolute expiration that we refresh on its session half-life. When I put it in local storage I set a timer for its absolute expiration. When I refresh the token and put it back in storage I cancel the previous timer. If the refresh fails for an extended period then the timer will eventually fire. It will forcefully remove the session from local storage since it is expired and it will broadcast (ngrx in my case but BehaviorSubject in yours) that the session has expired.

If you want to have a route change trigger an auth check just to be sure then you could do this:

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
    private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    get isLoggedIn() {
        this.loggedIn.next(localStorage.getItem('my-auth-key'));
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Since it is a behavior subject you can push a new value to it before you return it.

**EDIT**
Since you mentioned that you have to do `chrome.storage.sync.get` and it is async you could do the following (I'm not doing anything with parsing whatever comes out of storage):

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
    private loggedIn = new Subject<boolean>();

    get isLoggedIn() {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('my-auth-key', (isAuthenticated) => {
           this.loggedIn.next(isAuthenticated);
        });
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Note that I changed it to just `Subject` rather than `BehaviorSubject`. This will force the recipient to wait for the `.next` call. This assumes that you want to check the authentication state each time someone tries to subscribe.

The more elegant solution would be to subscribe to `chrome.storage.onChanged` to feed your BehaviorSubject. You would probably set that up in your constructor. Something like this... I have not used this api before so this is just the general idea... you may need to do null checks or do parsing or something... and if the values don't expire from the store then you would still need a timer to remove them to fire the change.

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
    private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    constructor(){
       chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, namespace) => {
          this.loggedIn.next(change['my-auth-key'].newValue);
       });
    }

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous. I can't use native local storage.

Comment: Good to know. See my edit. Same thing, but you do it in the callback. You could use a promise instead of an observable if you wished.

Comment: I tried this but value are false and always redirect to login. :(

Comment: @flpms Hmmm... your right... it being a behavior subject would do that to you. You would have to use a normal subject. I updated the answer. Did you try the `onChanged.addListener`?

Comment: The `onChanged.addListener` listen when change values in storage and sometimes I need check without any changes in storage, only to know token is valid or need another one. 

My objective is never logout user from extension after first login, and renew subsequents tokens after check is valid.

Comment: @flpms How do you know whether your token is valid? Does it have an absolute expiration known to the client? Is renewing it a manual operation performed by the client or is it a sliding expiration that is pushed based on server interaction but only the server knows the expiration?

Comment: Only the server knows. I will check after certain time from the last token.

Comment: @flpms So you get the token from cache on some interval and validate that it still works and if it doesn't you remove it from cache? If that is right then you should be firing the onChanged listener on remove.

Comment: Thats is correct I will use change to notify provider. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an observable out of chrome storage methods:

```
export class RxChromeStore {
   get(key: string): Observable<any> {
       return Observable.create(obs => {
           let cb = (err, data) => { // use whatever the chrome storage callback syntax is, this is typical cb structure
               if (err) {
                   obs.error(err);
               } else {
                   obs.next(data);
               }
           };
           chrome.storage.sync.get(key, cb);
       }).first();
   }
}

export class AuthService {
    private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return Observable.zip(RxChromeStore.get('your-auth-key'), this.loggedIn.asObservable(), (chromeAuth, authSubj) => chromeAuth || authSubj);
    }
}
```

your question is a little vague so I'm not sure what your exact goal is, but the basic point here is that you can always create an observable out of soemthing that is callback based using the create method, then you can treat it like any other observable:

```
RxChromeStore.get('auth-key').switchMap((auth) => (auth.invalid) ? this.http.get('reauthendpoint') : this.loggedIn.asObservable());
```

or whatever stream you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage variable to store/fetch data.

**Storing:**    `localStorage.setItem(key,value);`
**Fetching**: `localStorage.getItem(key);`

This localStorage variable is provided by typescript node_module which you will already been having in your angular project.

Comment: Sorry, but this don't solve my problem. I update the question to better understand the problem